# create a toggle navbar on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a toggle menu bar for php website.

html code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
        <div class="mini-submenu" >
        <img src="icons/nav_icon.png" height="30" width="30" >
        </div>

        <div class="list-group">
            <span href="#" class="list-group-item">
                Submenu
                <span class="pull-right" id="slide-submenu"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> Lorem ipsum</a>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

script code

```
$(function(){

    $('#slide-submenu').on('click',function() {                 
        $(this).closest('.list-group').fadeOut('slide',function(){
            $('.mini-submenu').fadeIn();    
        });

      });

    $('.mini-submenu').on('click',function(){       
        $(this).next('.list-group').toggle('slide');
        $('.mini-submenu').hide();
    })
})
```

At present the one that i have works fine but the problem is that when the first time i open the page the submenu that is under the nav_bar image gets opened automatically and when i click on cross button

[image]

then the nav_bar image appears like this

[image]

but what i want is opposite to it. i wish that whenever the page is loaded the image should appear first and when i click on the image the submenu should appear under it.

Answer (score 2):

change your script to

```
$(function(){
$('.list-group').hide();
$('.mini-submenu').show();

$(function(){

    $('#slide-submenu').on('click',function() {                 
        $(this).closest('.list-group').fadeOut('slide',function(){
            $('.mini-submenu').fadeIn();    
        });

      });

    $('.mini-submenu').on('click',function(){       
        $(this).next('.list-group').toggle('slide');
        $('.mini-submenu').hide();
    })
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine :

JavaScript:

```
(function($){
  $('.list-group').hide();
  $('#slide-submenu').on('click',function() {                 
    $(this).closest('.list-group').fadeOut('slide',function(){
     $('.mini-submenu').fadeIn();    
    });

  });

 $('.mini-submenu').on('click',function(){       
  $(this).next('.list-group').toggle('slide');
  $('.mini-submenu').hide();
 })
```

})(jQuery);